# using indirect to access a cell range in another sheet

Tags: excel

Here is some example data:

[image]

The goal is to access the sheet name May - then sum between the specified ranges (to / from) in cell header ( starting index position) and (grab index position of the maximum).

I can use the indirect function as below to achieve the sum I need

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'" &T8 & "'!d$8:m$9"))
```

However as my data changes - so will too the index position of the maximum value - hence I need to have indirect() grab these ranges from the cell values.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Cell data in May sheet as referenced: `d$9:o$9`

Formula above sums: `d$9:m$9` which = 36

[image]

Starting index = hard coded (does it matter?

Max location `=ADDRESS(CELL("row",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),))),CELL("col",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),))))`

Comment: Can you post more of your data? It is almost never a good idea to have a table like you have, which actually contains the cell locations to use as an input to something like `INDIRECT`. How are you determining these cell locations? Are they formulas or hardcoded? Either way, there is probably a better way to do this. Please post some example data in your `May` sheet that you want to sum.

Comment: This needs to be dynamic so didn't have a better way to grab the needed index locations. The data changes and as will the cell references (except starting cells)

Comment: Understood that the range is dynamic, but `INDEX` can handle dynamic ranges. The answer to your own question below is an absolute nightmare in my opinion. `INDIRECT` should be avoided like the plague. The only time I've found it unavoidable (within reason) is if the name of the sheet is dynamic. Even then `INDIRECT` can be avoided, just makes the formula longer. Anyway, if you're satisfied with the answer, then that is fine, but your solution looks extremely frail to me.

Comment: feel free to post an efficient answer - im fortunate that my data set is small - this is a collection of functions doing many things in one.

Comment: Again, I can't fully assess the situation because I have no idea what the data in your `May` sheet looks like.

Comment: the data in May is simply the values in the green row..... only in location: d$8:o$9

Comment: Such a small screenshot in your question, I didn't even noticed until now. But how could it be location `D8:O9`? Do you mean `D8:O8`? It only shows 1 row of data. Also it might be helpful to show if there are any row or column headers instead of showing the data with no context. I often make formulas to look for a certain row or column based on a header, then from there grab the row/column and perform whatever action I need to perform.

Comment: Yes sorry d$9:o$9

Comment: What about column/row headers? Seeing this data in context would be very helpful, especially since the ranges for another operation (`SUM` in this case) are dynamic.

Comment: There are none as the sheet had merged rows etc at the top..... its like a title - so not tabular data with row indexing or col names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!"&"d$9" & ":"&ADDRESS(CELL("row",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9"),))),CELL("col",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'"&C17&"'!d$9:o$9"),))))),0)
```

It works by:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&sheet name cell reference&"'!"&"starting cell id" & ":"& max value index position formula)
```

max value index position formula

```
=ADDRESS(CELL("row",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),))),CELL("col",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9")),INDIRECT("'" & C17 & "'!d$9:o$9"),))))
```